# MVC3 Azure - Forms Authentication - LogOff Failing miserably - I did a bad, bad thing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, forms-authentication

This holds true in IE, FireFox, and Chrome on dev box- including after manually deleting cookies in IE Internet Options
I sign in as a user, change password (works) and sign out.  I can then log in as the user with both the old and new password - a garbage password does fail authentication.
Log IN -
Change Password -
Sign Out -
Log In with old password again, Authenticates -
Sign Out -
Log In with New password, Authenticates -
Sign Out -
Log In with junk password fails of course
Rinse and Repeat - same behavior
Is there a code piece missing for the Azure part? Disconcerting - grrr
web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="15"></forms>
</authentication>
```

SignOff code:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        // Drop all the information held in the session
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();

        // clear authentication cookie
        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

        // clear session cookie
        HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
        foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            Request.Cookies.Remove(cookie);
        }
        // Redirect the user to the login page
        return RedirectToAction("LogOn"); 
    }
```

Comment: How are you storing the authentication information? Is it possible that you're saving multiple passwords for the same user?

Comment: Stored in a SQL table - No - I am not storing multiple passwords for the same user. Also, if I pick a user that I have not used in that browser I can not repeat the behavior. (Change in IE, then open Firefox, only the new one works).

Comment: You might want to try not Remove()ing all the cookies. That may be causing the server to not return them with the expiration date on them.

Comment: Nope - that doesn't work eihter.  That was actually an add on after the other didn't work.  I also tried this, that doesn't work, because when stepping through,  it is the cookie showing in the remove section.     (I can't get this to save my code block formatting now)<br/>
    HttpCookie cookie3 = new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH", "");
    cookie3.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie3);

Comment: Nope - that doesn't work eihter.  That was actually an add on after the other didn't work.  I also tried this, that doesn't work, because when stepping through,  it is the cookie showing in the remove section.    
   `HttpCookie cookie3 = new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH", "");
    cookie3.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie3);`  Thank you for trying, though.

Comment: Resolved!  Appears EF was caching  previously received entities  <http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/tag/dependency-injection/>  Force  a new membership provider instance to be created for that web request, and thus guarantee that the database context will not be holding a stale user entity.  Thank you Scattered Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see the answer spot!
Resolved! Appears EF was caching previously received entities [scatteredcode.wordpress.com/tag/dependency-injection/](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/tag/dependency-injection/)
Force a new membership provider instance to be created for that web request, and thus guarantee that the database context will not be holding a stale user entity. Thank you Scattered Code –